# Spring-boot AOP advice with CompletableFuture

Tags: spring-boot, aop, completable-future

I try to log with AOP for a `CompletableFuture` controller. `@Before` advice is working OK. But with `@AfterReturning` it is not working correctly in the exception case. I also tried with `@AfterThrowing`, which is not working either. When an exception occurs, my `@AfterReturning` advice also is not triggered and `@AfterThrowing` is never reached.

How can I use an AOP advice with exceptions in this case?

JController:

```java
@RestController
public class JController extends BaseExceptionHandler {
    @GetMapping(produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
    public CompletableFuture<BaseResponse> search() {
        final CompletableFuture result = asyncProcessor.process(request);
        return result;
    }
}
```

BaseExceptionHandler:

```java
public class BaseExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ResponseEntity handleException(final Exception exception) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(new ErrorResponse(Message.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, StatusCode.UNKNOWN_ERROR), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

AOP Class

```java
@AfterReturning(value = "execution(* com.xxx.xxx.controller.*.*(..))", returning = "result")
public void outgoingSuccess(final JoinPoint joinPoint, final CompletableFuture result) {
    LOGGER.debug("After Returning method: " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());     
}

@AfterThrowing("execution(* com.xxx.xxx.controller.*.*(..))")
public void outgoingError(final JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    LOGGER.debug("After Throwing method: " + joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());     
}
```

Comment: You are talking about AOP, but it looks like you forgot to post your aspect code. Please update the question. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. The next problem is that your sample code is just an incoherent set of snippets, not complete classes with package name (important for AOP!), imports etc. So I cannot use it like an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), just copy, compile and run it. You also did not provide the `@Before` advice you said was working. Could you please push a complete sample project to GitHub for me to clone and analyse? Just enough to reproduce your problem. Or do you expect me to create a full project and inject your snippets into it, guessing about what I cannot see here?